# Codeigniter like methods call?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter we use a method call like this

```
$this->load->view();
```

I wanna know what's "load" exactly ? Is it a function or what ? And why it doesn't have two parentheses after it ? I wanna make something like this in my code so how can I do this ?

Comment: Note that () are parentheses, while braces are {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load`, a property on the object `$this`, is an instance of the [`CI_Loader`](http://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/tip/system/core/Loader.php) class. It has a method called `view()`.

CodeIgniter instantiates the `Loader` object in a fairly obtuse way, but you can visualize it like this:

```
class Loader {
  function view($view_name) {
    echo "View '$view_name' loaded!";
  }
}

class FooController{
  public $load;

  function __construct() {
    $this->load = new Loader();
  }
}

$foo = new FooController();
$foo->load->view("bar"); // => "View 'bar' loaded!"
/* ^    ^     ^
   |    |     |
   |    |     +--- view() is a method on the Loader object assigned to $foo's 'load' property
   |    |
   |    +--------- 'load' is a property on $foo, to which we've assigned an object of class Loader
   |
   +-------------- $foo is an instance of class FooController
*/
```

Comment: Can we make an instance of a class in an another class definition ?

Comment: Yes. Class definitions are global, so once PHP knows about a class we can create instances of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
class Controller {
    public $load = new Loader();
    //...
}
```

Then, you can access properties and methods on `$load` like this:

```
$controller = new Controller();
$controller->load->foo();
```

In CI, `$load` is just a property of the `CI_Controller` class, and an instance of the `CI_Loader` class.